# How to transfer data between C++ project and DLL in C++ with CUDA in the correct way?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, dll, cuda

I have a C++ project which uses DLL in C++ with CUDA.

Now I'm passing 2 pointers from the main project to DLL. Inside DLL, the arrays will be copy to device memory. Some calculation will be done with them. And then, the arrays will be copy back to host.

I heard that the data transfering will be better with data overlap method. But how can I do it in this case? The copy function `cudaMemcpyAsync` requires pinned memory to be asynchronous and the passed pointers are not, right?

I'm using the temporary solution is to use `memcpy` to copy passed arrays to pinned arrays. Then, I use streams to overlap data. After that, use `memcpy` again to copy from pinned memory arrays to passed arrays. And the CPU stuff is clearly not a good way here, I think.

And can we do something like passing pinned memory arrays from main project to DLL when both are with CUDA?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can convert simple host memory to pinned memory using [`cudaHostRegister`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141).

Comment: This seems to be the one, I'll check. Thanks man.

Comment: @sgar91 please post your recommendation to use `cudaHostRegister()` as an answer. That way Harry can accept it and people will know the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory allocated by standard C/C++ allocators i.e. `malloc` and `new` can be converted to page locked memory by using the CUDA Runtime function [`cudaHostRegister`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141), which can be used to overlap asynchronous memory copies b/w host and device. Be advised; don't forget to unpin the memory which has been pinned using the mentioned function. Use [`cudaHostUnregister`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc07b1312c60ca36c118e2ed71b192afe) to unpin the memory. If memory is not unpinned, undesired results may be produced. e.g. a function may try to pin the memory which has already been pinned. or pinned memory may be freed using `free` or `delete` which is undefined behavior.